# Delete a sizegrip between scrollbars MFC

Tags: mfc, scrollbar

I'd like to delete a sizegrip between horizontal and vertical scrollbars in MFC(example in picture). Is it possible? [image: Example]

Comment: If you want to remove it because the parent window is not resizable, try removing the necessary border styles from the parent.